# iOS – Plain UITableView with custom cell background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView` in plain mode because I want to have the sticky section headers. I have a custom background image which is set for the cell's `backgroundView` but this image gets stretched the whole width of the `UITableView`.

How can I prevent it from getting stretched? I've tried setting `UIViewContentModeCenter` to no avail but I don't really know which view to set it to (the tableview, the cell? the cell's contentView?)

Comment: Try `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` and see if those fit correctly.

Comment: How did you set background image? Did you set UIImageView as backgroundView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually didn't try to set `UIViewContentModeCenter` on the `backgroundView`. So setting that made the image not stretch.

Answer (score 0):

The background view is always made to fit the whole cell. So you have a container view -

```
UIView *cntr = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:<whole cell frame>]
[cntr addSubview:myCustomView];
```